# System.NullReferenceException creating viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, umbraco

So, I'm trying to find the Umbraco node (as iPublishedContent), and pass it to the viewModel (as Ш've hijacked a route). So i put this in my controller:

```
private AddCouponCodesViewModel viewModel;
public AddCouponCodesController(){
    //Get iPublished content
    IPublishedContent content = Umbraco.TypedContent(1225);
    //Pass to viewModel
    viewModel = new AddCouponCodesViewModel(content);
    RouteData.DataTokens["umbraco"] = content;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //return view etc
}
```

But I'm getting

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

here:

```
 Source Error(AddCouponCodesViewModel.cs): 
 Line 20: 
 Line 21:         }
 Line 22:         public AddCouponCodesViewModel(IPublishedContent content)
 Line 23:             : base(content)
 Line 24:         {
```

AddCouponCodeRenderModel.cs:

```
public class AddCouponCodesViewModel : RenderModel
    {
    public string test { get; set; }
    public List<string> tables { get; set; }
    public List<string> errors { get; set; }

    public AddCouponCodesViewModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base(content, culture)
    {

    }
    public AddCouponCodesViewModel(IPublishedContent content)
        : base(content)
    {

    }
```

And this is the Global.asax

```
public class Global : UmbracoApplication
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted(sender, e);

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        //FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        base.OnApplicationStarting(sender, e);

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "AddCouponCodes",                                              // Route name
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "AddCouponCodes", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
         );


    }

}
```

The content is published (I've checked and double checked), and the node ID is correct.

What I'm basically trying to do here, is to get the route example.com/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{parameter}
To be routed, but having problems connecting it with the umbracoNode (And class RenderModel requires a iPublishContent object as a parameter, but I'm in no luck when trying to pass it anything)

Could someone please help me here, been stuck way too many hours on this :-(

Comment: You should show the code for the class `RenderModel`.  Based on where you said the error is occurring, it looks like the error is happening inside of the constructor of that class.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, if you are hijacking a route, it means that you are overriding the way Umbraco passes it's `RenderModel` to one of it's published pages. You can either do this globally by overriding the main `RenderMvcController`, or you can override on a `DocumentType`-specific basis. So for example, if I have a Homepage doc type, I could create:

```
public HomepageController : RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        // Create your new renderModel here, inheriting
        // from RenderModel

        return CurrentTemplate(renderModel);
    }
}
```

This would route all calls to the homepage through this one action. For this, you *don't* need to define any new routes in the route table. And you should override the render model in the action *not in the constructor*.

Your question is slightly confusing and it's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve because:

- You have defined a route, and
- In your constructor you are calling `Umbraco.TypedContent(1225)` to retrieve a specific published node

So ... if the admin page you are trying to route has itself been published by Umbraco (and it doesn't sound like it has), the just create a new controller with the name of the page's document type and override the render model in the way described above.

However ... if your admin page hasn't been published by Umbraco and you just want the admin page to access node data, then you have a couple of options:

- Create a surface controller, inheriting from SurfaceController. This will give you access to the Umbraco context et al; or
- Create a standard controller (preferrably in an Area) and inject the `ContentCache` using something like Autofac

E.g.:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof (AdminController).Assembly)
       .WithParameter("contentCache", UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache);
```

- Create a standard controller (preferrably in an Area)  and access the node using Umbraco's `ContentService` API, i.e. `new Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService().GetById(1225)`

The difference between the last two approaches is that:

- Injecting the `ContentCache` provides you readonly but very quick access to the *published* content.
- Accessing the `ContentService` provides you read/write access to the nodes themselves but at the expense of speed as you are querying the database directly.

It depends on what your requirement is.

Either way, it is well worth taking time to read through the [documentation for hijacking Umbraco routes](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/custom-controllers), and at least trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, I do have a umbraco node, not that i really need it. Just getting into umbraco / MVC, and it's kindof confusing, but I'm beginning to get the grasp of it. Thanks so much for a detailed answer :-)

Comment: To clarify, i have my adminpanel at /Admin and want the various controllers (admin actions) to be mapped to Admin/{Controller}/{action}, preferably with matching umbraco nodes, as i might get use for them later on.

Comment: But is your "admin panel" published by Umbraco? If it is then you need to hijack the routes as I describe. If the admin panel isn't published by Umbraco but you are actually just wanting to access Umbraco nodes within the admin panel, then you *don't* want to 'hijack' the routes. You just need to access Umbraco's `ContentCache`. If you don't want to use injection, you can access the `ContentService` via the API using new Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService().GetById(1225). See here for details: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Models/Content

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can tell you that your view isn't getting fed anything for the Razor markup because your Index method doesn't feed it anything.  That's one problem.  I can also tell you, that in your AddCouponCodesViewModel, you'll need an empty constructor, so that the razor syntax can just create an instance, and then populate it to match your submitted object to the view.

Modify your ViewController :

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
        return View(viewModel);
  }
```

Modify your AddCouponCodesViewModel to add an Empty constructor:

```
public AddCouponCodesViewModel()
{
}
```

Comment: The compiler generates an empty constructor by default, so it's redundant to create one yourself.

Comment: ^That, and RenderModel (An umbraco class(?)) can't have a parameterless constuctor.

Comment: @HenkMollema Take a look above.  Once you make a constructor it no longer generates one that is empty.  Just as a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Create a paramaterless constructor on your view model like this:

```
 public AddCouponCodesViewModel(): 
    this(new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).
TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId))
   {
   }
```

This will get the contexts your other constructors are looking for.
After you've created a class with specific constructors, the compiler stops generating a parameterless one by default. Since you need a parameterless constructor, this is how to get one and still pass in the Umbraco contextual info your viewmodel needs

Comment: What do i have to include to get UmbracoHelper, and UmbracoContext? Cant find any documentation on the classes, so i have no idea what to import. Tried Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper and Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext, Visual finds the classes, but still getting error that its not in the current context(Sorry for kindof stupid question here)

Comment: @Duncanmhor You can't do this, because you are not within the Umbraco context, so `UmbracoContext.Current` will be null. This is also a bad approach because a) If you have access to the `UmbracoContext`, then there is never a reason to spin up a new `UmbracoHelper`. This is just unnecessary code duplication, b) you are introducing potential exceptions into a constructor which should always be avoided, and c) you are pushing a concrete instance into the constructor parameter when the good guys on the Umbraco team have gone to the trouble of making things as loosely coupled as they can.